# What is a single-word adjective for: "unable to help"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use an emotionally-charged **adjective** to express someone who **witnesses** the grave situation but **cannot help** in any manner. The context of the word:

> My grandfather narrated how during WWII, his step-father’s entire household starved to death. Imagining the gradual death of those children and a ___ mother made my eyes swell.

I want to use one word to describe the mother here as *observing everything but unable to help*.

Also, it would be extremely helpful if someone could make a suggestion on how to make this part sound better.

Comment: Avoid asking for items or ideas. Subjective questions will be closed unless the request is expert-level, unique, particularly interesting and thought-provoking, shows substantial effort and research, and demands responses that meet these same standards. See: “[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: Avoid word or phrase requests except when accompanied by: (i) your criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unusual word, such as *hobbled*, would be apt if you were to expand the context of your scenario and add some poignant details to it. Since [hobbled][1] means impeded, hindered or hampered from moving, you would probably need to add a word such as *completely*, since being hobbled does not necessarily prevent any progress whatever, but only some progress.

In other words, you would need explain how and why the mother was *completely* and *totally* prevented from helping her starving family.

Interestingly, one of the reasons a horse is put through "hobble training" is to teach it patience should the horse one day be caught and trapped by, say, some barbed wire or a vine. Since the natural, instinctual behavior of a horse in that situation is to panic, waste energy and perhaps injure itself in attempting to free itself, hobble training teaches the horse to be calm and to wait for its master to free it from whatever is hobbling it.

You say you "want to use an emotionally-charged adjective to express someone who witnesses the grave situation but cannot help in any manner," so my suggestion is to expand the context and add some detail to clarify why the mother is completely hobbled. For example,

> My grandfather narrated how during WWII, his stepfather’s entire household starved to death. Imagining the gradual death of those children and a mother who was completely hobbled by her captors, preventing her from helping her family, made my eyes well up with tears.

(Notice I replaced "eyes swell" with "eyes well up with tears." I don't think there is such a thing as swollen eyes, unless there is a physiological problem such as hyperthyroidism.

[1]: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hobbled## Heading ##

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps helpless, powerless, incapable, or even derelict might work? Why is the mother unable to help? The situation sounds truely dire, and desperate. Some dastardly plot no doubt. So nice job, I can't wait to see what word is chosen.

How about debilatated, constricted, restricted, confined, handicaped, decimated, or befuddled? Seems many words might work.

Answer (score -1):

I believe "tormented"  is an emotionally-charged adjective you can use here. You can also use destitute, wrecked, crippled.